# Raspbian boot issue after script installed

Tags: raspbian, boot, noobs

I have installed Raspbian from NOOBS onto Raspberry Pi.
The RPi booted fine until I tried to install a program.
Now I think it is trying to run a script on boot-up which is causing it to fail.

If I hold shift - I get back to the GUI desktop (I assume this is in recovery mode).
How do I now get the RPi to boot up without holding the shift key?

Sorry - totally new at RPi and Raspbian

Thanks
Scott

Comment: What program did you install?

Comment: I was trying to install a UPS software (UPSilon 2000).

Comment: Have just tried a trick that I found on the web - which seems like it will get me back to square one (which is what I want)... When I was pressing left shift button - I don't think anything was happening - and was somehow managing to get back into the GUI... but now I have swapped the keyboard to the top USB port, and the mouse on the bottom one, and have held down the shift button - and now I think I am truly in recovery mode. Noobs is now asking me which operating system I want to install. This will hopefully erase my problem, and then I can start all over again. Not an issue in my case..

Comment: ok - that did not work.

Comment: Am still getting "timeout waiting for hardware interrupt" errors.

Comment: Am going to try to install one of the other OS (like Archlinux) to see if I have any luck with that one.

Comment: Potentially sounds like a dead SD card.

Comment: Ok - have managed to successfully install all the other NOOBS operating systems (individually) - but when I install Raspbian - I get these errors. On my last attempt, I went into recovery mode, made a slight edit to the config, and upon exit - the RPi booted up to the GUI. When rebooted - same issue, rebooted again, went into recovery mode, undid my last edit, upon exit the RPi booted to the GUI.

Comment: Before I got these issues, I was also mucking around with USB sticks attached to a powered 7-port hub. Is it possible that mounted USB stick that has not been unmounted properly could cause these issues?

Comment: Ok - now I think I have solved the issue. Looks like I have been going on a wild goose chase - had nothing to do with the software installation or scripts. It looks like it is my keyboard that is causing the issue. I have one of those flexible - roll-up USB keyboards. If I boot up without the keyboard plugged in, it boots up fine. Once up and running in the Raspbian GUI, I can then plug in my keyboard, and everything works fine. I can plug in my mouse and my USB hub before boot-up without issue, but if I try to boot up with this keyboard plugged in - the issue re-appears.

Comment: I might try a different keyboard to see if the problem exists with all keyboards - or just my roll-up version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems with the Raspberry Pi booting up have now been resolved.
When booting up using Raspbian OS - I was getting heaps of "timeout waiting for hardware interrupt" errors. The screen would scroll really quickly, then timeout errors would ensue, and it seemed like an endless loop. At first I could not get into recovery mode, but once I eliminated a 7-port powered USB hub from the equation, it would respond to the shift key (ie. by plugging keyboard and mouse directly into Rpi USB sockets). I tried installing some of the other operating systems that come with NOOBS, and I did not experience the hardware interrupt errors with the other operating systems, but when I installed Raspbian - the GUI would fail to boot. ANd I really wanted to to stick to Raspbian.

I did manage to get into the GUI every now and then by jumping into and out of the config file (in recovery mode), but this was not satisfactory.
I then experimented with booting without anything but an HDMI cable (and power) attached.
Suddenly, the GUI loaded without issue. I could then insert mouse and keyboard after the OS had booted up into the GUI. 
I booted up with mouse inserted on its own. But when I tried keyboard on its own - the problem returned.
So this pointed to an issue with the keyboard. I was able to boot up without the keyboard and then successfully use the keyboard by plugging it in after boot up.
I then tried the RPi attached to a monitor instead of TV - by using a HDMI to DVI cable. I had no problem booting up with keyboard attached.

So I am putting my problem down to a combination of a
 - rollup keyboard used in conjunction with a TV (using HDMI cable).

Possibly a power related issue - maybe the combination of keyboard and TV was drawing too much current from RPi on bootup? Who knows... but my problem is solved. 
I now can boot up successfully without any further issue.